# Split string with some known characters and unknown two digits in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, split, wildcard, digits

I have strings

```
some.text.S**01**E02.partofstring.mkv
some.textstring.S**01**E02.partofstring.mkv
```

I need to extract the numbers between S and E. In those filenames always are two digits.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried. We are here to support programmers and enthusiasts. However we are not a code writing service. [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with a capture group: `.*?S.*?(\d{2}).*?E.*`

```
> "some.text.S**01**E02.partofstring.mkv" -replace '.*?S.*?(\d{2}).*?E.*','$1'
01
> "some.textstring.S**01**E02.partofstring.mkv" -replace '.*?S.*?(\d{2}).*?E.*','$1'
01
```